# Does it matter whether I use standard library preprocessor includes in my header file vs. the corresponding implementation file?

Tags: c++

If I have a project with

```
main .cpp 
Knife .h and .cpp
Cucumber .h and .cpp
```

and I want to use Knife's members in Cucumber, does it matter whether I use the following:

```
#include "Knife.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

in Cucumber.h or Cucumber.cpp (assume that Cucumber.cpp already has an include for Cucumber.h)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation is to minimize the number of files included in the header files.
So, if I have the choice, I prefer to include in the source file.

When you modify a header file, all the files that include this header file must be recompiled.

So, if `cucumber.h` includes `knife.h`, and `main.cpp` includes `cucumber.h`, and you modify `knife.h`, all the files will be recompiled (`cucumber.cpp`, `knife.cpp` and `main.cpp`).

If `cucumber.cpp` includes `knife.h` and `main.cpp` includes `cucumber.h`, and you modify `knife.h`, only `cucumber.cpp` and `knife.cpp`will be recompiled, so your compilation time is reduced.

If you need to use knife in cucumber you can proceed like this:

```
// Cucumber.hpp
#ifndef CUCUMBER_HPP
#define CUCUMBER_HPP

class Knife;

class Cucumber
{
public :
///...
    private :
    Knife* myKnife
}
#endif

//Cucumber.cpp
#include "Cucumber.hpp"
#include "Knife.hpp

// .. your code here
```

This "trick" is called "forward declaration". That is a well-known trick of C++ developers, who want to minimize compilation time.

Comment: yes, the trick is to define class knife rather include the header file. The Compiler understand it like this :"A class Knife exist, and you will see later what it the content of this class". Then when you include the header file (in cucumber.cpp), the compiler know what is in the class knife

Answer (score 2):

yes, you should put it in the `.cpp` file.

you will have faster builds, fewer dependencies, and fewer artifacts and noise -- in the case of iostream, GCC declares:

```
// For construction of filebuffers for cout, cin, cerr, clog et. al.
static ios_base::Init __ioinit;
```

within namespace `std`. that declaration is going to produce a ton of (redundant) static data which must be constructed at startup, if `Knife.h` is included by many files. so there are a lot of wins, the only loss is that you must explicitly include the files you actually need -- every place you need them (which is also a very good thing in some regards).

Answer (score 1):

The advice I've seen advocated was to only include the minimum necessary for a given source file, and to keep as many includes out of headers as possible.  It potentially reduces the dependencies when it comes time to compile.

Another thing to note is your namespace usage.  You definitely want to be careful about having that sort of thing in a header.  It could change namespace usage in files you didn't plan on.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, try to add your includes into the implementation file rather than the header for the following reasons:

- Reduces potential unnecessary inclusion and keeps it to only where needed.
- Reduces compile time (quite significantly in some cases I've seen.) Avoids over exposing implementation details.
- Reduces risk of circular dependencies appearing.
- Avoids locking users of your headers into having to indirectly include files that they may not want / need to.

If you reference a class by pointer or reference only in your header then it's not necessary to include the appropriate header; a class declaration will suffice.

Probably there are quite a few other reasons - the above are probably the most important / obvious ones.